# How to mimic Expand with Thread?

Tags: programming, mapthread, algebraic-manipulation

I want to mimic `Expand[(a + b) (c + d)]` with `Thread`.

My attempt below does not provide the correct result:

```
Thread[Times[a + b, c + d], Plus]
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: Multiplication is not really equivalent to threading, which matches up objects/terms in parallel. This is a way to use `Thread` to do it, but you have to use `Thread` at least twice to achieve multiplication: `Thread[ReleaseHold[#], Plus] & /@ Thread[Times[Hold[a + b], c + d], Plus]`

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thank you very much. Very useful!

Comment: Maybe thread twice, like this `Thread[#, Plus] & /@ Thread[Times[a + b, c + d], Plus, 1]`

Comment: You're welcome! Another remark: `Outer` seems more aligned with multiplication than `Thread`: `Outer[Times, a + b, c + d] == Expand[(a + b) (c + d)]`

Comment: @LouisB: Very good answer. It is simpler than using `Hold`. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thank you for informing `Outer`. It is useful.